# Eclipse editor code editing

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax, editor

First of all, I was unsure what the title of this question should be so I just gave it my best shot. I just started using Eclipse as my IDE, it's a great IDE and all but I get annoyed when I highlight a portion of code to be edited  or replaced, any code after it gets deleted. So for example:

```
System.out.println(theScanner.nextLine());
```

I want to replace `nextLine` with `nextDouble.` I would highlight `nextLine` and type in `nextDouble` but then the ()()(); would be erased and I would have to type them in again. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Click `Windows > Preferences`. Type **content assist** in search box. Select `Completion overwrites` option as shown below

[image]

Keep cursor after character `t` then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Then type `d` then select `nextDouble` method press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]